# Creacion de timer cuenta regresiva

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Busco crear una cuenta regresiva iniciando en 3:00 minutos, pero no tengo claro como hacerlo.

```js
startTimer() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      if(this.timeLeft > 0) {
        this.timeLeft--;
      } else {
        this.timeLeft = 60;
      }
    },1000)
  }

  pauseTimer() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
```

Comment: https://pablomonteserin.com/cuenta-regresiva/

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu duda?

Comment: Con el código actual puedo hacer una cuenta regresiva de 60 segundos a 0 segundos, lo que busco es que el marcador inicie en 3:00 y culmine en 0:00.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hacer una cuenta regresiva, puedes crear una variable con una fecha cualquier pero con el tiempo que tenga tres minutos `2020-01-01 00:03`. Luego ir restándole los segundos hasta que llegue a cero. A continuación se muestra un ejemplo que solo llegará hasta 02:45 por motivos de la demostración:

```js
var date = new Date('2020-01-01 00:03');

// Función para rellenar con ceros
var padLeft = n => "00".substring(0, "00".length - n.length) + n;

// Asignar el intervalo a una variable para poder eliminar el intervale cuando llegue al limite
var interval = setInterval(() => {

  // Asignar el valor de minutos
  var minutes = padLeft(date.getMinutes() + "");
  // Asignqr el valor de segundos
  var seconds = padLeft(date.getSeconds() + "");
  
  console.log(minutes, seconds);
  
  // Restarle a la fecha actual 1000 milisegundos
  date = new Date(date.getTime() - 1000);
    
  // Si llega a 2:45, eliminar el intervalo
  if( minutes == '02' && seconds == '45' ) {
    clearInterval(interval); 
  }
  
}, 1000);
```